# automatically changing variable values once they are defined

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to write some code to satisfy this RSpec requirement (abridged)

```
@book = Book.new

@book.title = "inferno"
@book.title.should == "Inferno"
```

I am not sure how one would make `@book.title` change from "inferno" to "Inferno" automatically once it is defined, nor do I know where to look. I have looked at the documentation for instance variables and the documentation for initialization, but the solution became clear from neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can acheive this by overriding the setter method:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other stuff ...

  def title=(str)
    write_attribute(:title, str.capitalize)
  end
end
```

or, alternatively:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other stuff ...

  def title=(str)
    self[:title] = str.capitalize
  end
end
```

You may need to take additional processing into consideration, since `String#capitalize` may not be sufficient for your needs. Example:

```
'foo'.capitalize
#=> "Foo"

'foo of bar'.capitalize
#=> "Foo of bar"
```

One possible solution for this would be as follows:

```
'foo'.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
#=> "Foo"

'foo of bar'.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
#=> "Foo Of Bar"
```

But be aware that this brings about different problems. Most notably, this will discard any leading, trailing and repeated whitespace:

```
' foo of     bar '.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
#=> "Foo Of Bar"
```

You will have to decide for yourself whether this meets your needs or not, but you get the basic idea.

Comment: It's the argument to the setter method, i.e. the value right of the equals sign. For example when you call `@book.title = 'foobar'`, the string `'foobar'` will be available as argument. This argument is called `str` in this case, but you can name it however you want.

Comment: ok it seems to me to be a bit easier to do `self.title =` instead of `self[:title] = ` or `write_attribute(:title,` but perhaps it's not significant. Specifically, I'm not sure I really understand you're two snippets there.

Comment: When you write `self.title = ...` you call the method itself, therefore entering an infinite recursive loop. This will result in a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`. `self[:title] = ...` and `write_attribute(:title, ...)` however operate at a lower level and thus prevent this error.

Comment: thanks! it's over my head why they operate 'at a lower level' but I suppose I'll probably pick it up eventually.

Comment: Well, the `title=()` method that Rails automagically generates for you behind the scenes also uses one of these methods. So you are really overwriting the original setter in the same manner, but adding a call to `capitalize`. Hope that helps you understand.