# I am having trouble upcasing or capitalizing

Tags: ruby

I cannot understand why `word` is not capitalized or upcased.

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  def title=(changed_title)
    changed_title.split(" ").map!{|word|
      word.to_s.capitalize
      }.join(" ")
    @title = changed_title
  end
end

book = Book.new
book.title = "check"
puts book.title
# >> check
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`split(' ')` generates a temporary array. `map!` mutates that array. And then it's gone (because it wasn't assigned to anything).

`changed_title` remains in its original state (`"check"`), it was not mutated.

Here's a fix:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title
  def title=(changed_title)
    @title = changed_title.split(" ").map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  end
end

book = Book.new
book.title = "check"
puts book.title
# >> Check
```

Comment: thanks lots, and do you mind explaining the &:capitalize portion (specifically the &: part), I've seen it before, but couldn't find it in the docs. Is it just a shorthand for doing one method on whatever is mapped?

Comment: @macsplean: yeah, exactly, just a shorthand. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1961030/125816), for example.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively do

```
def title=(changed_title)
  @title = changed_title.gsub(/\w+/, &:capitalize)
end
```

The regex matches all words (one or more word characters, to be precise). `gsub` replaces all occurences with the return value of the block, which takes one match at a time and capitalizes it. Finally, the value is assigned to `@title`.

*Edit* — As pointed out by @SergioTulentsev, this will yield different results, e.g. the method originally used in the question will yield:

- `"$hello"` → `"$hello"`
- `"   foo  bar "` → `"Foo Bar"`

The method presented in this answer will however yield:

- `"$hello"` → `"$Hello"`
- `"   foo  bar "` → `"   Foo  Bar "`

Comment: This does something different. `title = '$hello'`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev good observation. However, the question is related to  [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488307/automatically-changing-variable-values-once-they-are-defined/19488328#19488328), where I gave the initial idea for the code the OP is asking about. Now I think the capitalization method posted here is just as good for the use case, but shorter.

Comment: I prefer not to use regexes when I can (I'm not too smart), but your code is sure shorter. :)

Comment: I can understand that, regexes can really get confusing. But when i have the option of using a short regex to write short code, i prefer this over long code. After all, short code is often easier to read. Although again with regexes that's not necessarily the case :)

Comment: Btw as pointed out in the previous question the `split` way will also discard whitespace, e.g. ` foo  bar ` --> `Foo Bar` while the method posted here will preserve whitespace.

Comment: I like this one... so *+1*.

Comment: Well, it depends on OP's needs. Maybe he needs to collapse whitespace.

Comment: But then again, maybe collapsing whitespace should be a separate step and not happen "magically" in the background. It may not be obvious from the code that whitespace is collapsed, which I think is not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

```
def title=(changed_title)
  @title = changed_title.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
```

or if you using rails

```
# require if not rails app
#require 'rails'
# or to not require all rails as @p11y suggested
#require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'

def title=(changed_title)
  @title = changed_title.titleize
end
```

Comment: Or, even more consise: @title = changed_title.split.map(&:capitalize)*' '

Comment: @MoMolog you will probably have much fun on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com :-)

Comment: `require 'rails'` is a bit overkill. You can exclusively require the `String#titleize` method with `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'`

Comment: @MoMolog `*' '` is too confusing and crypty, but agree to split

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "a big brown fox"
a = a.split.map(&:capitalize!).join(" ") #=> A Big Brown Fox
```